# Ubuntu WIFI stops working and system breaks

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, laptop, 20.04

I have a dell XPS 15 9570 laptop. I have been using Ubuntu (18, 19 and 20) for the last two years. Everything work fine except for the wifi, which randomly stops working. Sometimes I can just turn off and on the wifi and it comes to work until next random crash. However, other times, when it happens, I cannot turn off wifi, it seems like the system breaks, I have to hard shutdown the laptop and after boot it works again.

Current ubuntu verion:

```
20.04 LTS
```

Kernel:

```
5.4.0-26-generic
```

bios version (`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`):

```
1.15.0
```

This is the output of `sudo lshw -class network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: wlp59s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:bd:20:01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-26-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.46 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:141 memory:ed200000-ed3fffff
```

Output of `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  6
thunderbolt           167936  0
rfcomm                 81920  4
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 24576  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  2
btusb                  57344  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb
bluetooth             581632  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    28672  1 ecdh_generic
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              225280  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
kvm_intel             286720  0
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
joydev                 24576  0
nvidia_uvm            966656  0
nvidia_drm             45056  12
nvidia_modeset       1114112  7 nvidia_drm
mei_hdcp               24576  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_sof_pci            20480  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    69632  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      20480  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               106496  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    32768  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core          245760  3 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
aesni_intel           372736  8
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
dell_laptop            24576  0
nvidia              20430848  482 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
ledtrig_audio          16384  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof,dell_laptop
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_hda_intel          53248  6
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           90112  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
ath10k_pci             49152  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
ath10k_core           475136  1 ath10k_pci
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
intel_rapl_perf        20480  0
ath                    36864  1 ath10k_core
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
mac80211              843776  1 ath10k_core
dell_wmi               20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
i915                 1986560  4
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
serio_raw              20480  0
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
dcdbas                 20480  1 dell_smbios
cfg80211              704512  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
snd                    90112  25 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
rtsx_pci_ms            24576  0
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
hid_multitouch         28672  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
drm_kms_helper        184320  2 nvidia_drm,i915
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler       106496  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 40960  1
processor_thermal_device    24576  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei                   106496  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
intel_rapl_common      24576  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_device
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
typec_ucsi             40960  1 ucsi_acpi
typec                  45056  1 typec_ucsi
int3403_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
intel_hid              20480  0
dell_smo8800           20480  0
int3400_thermal        20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,dell_wmi
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
acpi_pad              184320  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  1
dell_smm_hwmon         20480  0
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   491520  14 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
usbhid                 57344  0
hid_generic            16384  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         28672  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
psmouse               155648  0
nvme                   49152  5
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
i2c_i801               32768  0
nvme_core             102400  7 nvme
rtsx_pci               69632  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
ahci                   40960  0
idma64                 20480  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_hid                28672  0
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
hid                   131072  4 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
pinctrl_cannonlake     36864  0
wmi                    32768  6 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor,mxm_wmi
pinctrl_intel          28672  1 pinctrl_cannonlak
```

Output of `dmesg | grep ath10` when the error happens

```
[    4.511597] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.515050] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    4.794546] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[    4.794548] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    4.794952] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[    4.859617] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 4ac0889b
[    4.957186] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    4.976154] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    5.067954] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0 wlp59s0: renamed from wlan0
[  645.565783] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 7807.422028] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[ 7807.422035] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[ 7807.422038] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[ 7810.497976] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: wmi command 20482 timeout, restarting hardware
[ 7810.497993] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to delete WMI vdev 1: -11
[ 7810.498194] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to set 2g txpower 26: -108
[ 7810.498199] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to setup tx power 26: -108
[ 7810.498202] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to recalc tx power: -108
[ 7810.498231] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to set inactivity time for vdev 0: -108
[ 7810.498234] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to setup powersave: -108
[ 7813.553447] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
[ 7816.577730] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
[ 7816.577732] ath10k_warn: 1 callbacks suppressed
[ 7816.577733] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to wait for target init: -110
[ 7816.578915] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to set inactivity time for vdev 0: -108
[ 7816.578916] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to setup powersave: -108
[ 7816.578918] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to set PS Mode 0 for vdev 0: -108
[ 7816.578919] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to setup powersave: -108
[ 7816.578920] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to setup ps on vdev 0: -108
[ 7816.579115] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
[ 7816.579245] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to delete peer c6:b4:22:66:7d:b6 for vdev 0: -108
[ 7816.579289] Modules linked in: msr ccm thunderbolt rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel uvcvideo bluetooth videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common ecdh_generic ecc videodev mc x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi nvidia_uvm(OE) crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match aesni_intel snd_soc_acpi joydev snd_soc_core crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine mei_hdcp nvidia_drm(POE) intel_rapl_msr nvidia_modeset(POE) intel_cstate dell_laptop ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event intel_rapl_perf snd_rawmidi ath10k_pci ath10k_core snd_seq dell_wmi
[ 7816.579614] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[ 7816.579615] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to set cts protection for vdev 0: -108
```

another example of `dmesg | grep ath10` when the error happens

```
[   88.939853] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   89.101352] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   89.475498] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[   89.475500] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   89.475862] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[   89.541655] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 4ac0889b
[   89.621172] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   89.640347] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   89.731981] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0 wlp59s0: renamed from wlan0
[  120.195291] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[16515.063978] Modules linked in: ccm thunderbolt rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic joydev nvidia_uvm(OE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress aesni_intel ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine dell_laptop nvidia(POE) ledtrig_audio crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper intel_cstate snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi ath10k_pci snd_seq_midi_event ath10k_core snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_perf ath snd_seq
[19918.586631] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[20648.069078] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[20648.069085] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[20648.069088] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[20651.140485] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: wmi command 20482 timeout, restarting hardware
[20651.140500] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to delete WMI vdev 1: -11
[20651.140663] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to set 2g txpower 26: -108
[20651.140667] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to setup tx power 26: -108
[20651.140670] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to recalc tx power: -108
[20651.140695] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to set inactivity time for vdev 0: -108
[20651.140698] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to setup powersave: -108
[20654.196066] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
[20657.223918] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
[20657.223920] ath10k_warn: 6 callbacks suppressed
[20657.223921] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to wait for target init: -110
[20657.224881] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 2): 1250
[20657.225065] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to delete peer c6:b4:22:66:7d:b6 for vdev 0: -108
[20657.225116] Modules linked in: ccm thunderbolt rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic joydev nvidia_uvm(OE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress aesni_intel ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine dell_laptop nvidia(POE) ledtrig_audio crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper intel_cstate snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi ath10k_pci snd_seq_midi_event ath10k_core snd_rawmidi intel_rapl_perf ath snd_seq
[20657.225363] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[20657.225364] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to set cts protection for vdev 0: -108
[20657.225366] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to set erp slot for vdev 0: -108
[20657.225367] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to set preamble for vdev 0: -108
[20657.225368] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to down vdev 0: -108
[20657.225370] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to submit vdev param txbf 0x0: -108
[20657.225370] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to recalc txbf for vdev 0: -108
[20803.686593] Workqueue: phy0 ath10k_scan_timeout_work [ath10k_core]
[20803.68
```

6639]  ath10k_scan_timeout_work+0x23/0x40 [ath10k_core]

I guess it could be related with the `unsupported HTC service id` or `failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out`  or `wmi command 20482 timeout, restarting hardware` shown in the output of `dmesg`. But cannot figure out the problem.

I have been trying to solve this problem for more than one year. I have tried different solutions found in different forums, none of them worked for me.

Comment: Report a bug to Launchpad. It makes no sense to post it here.

Comment: @Pilot6 where should I post it? Thank you

Comment: Run `ubuntu-bug linux` and follow directions.

Comment: Done. I have reported as a bug too. I leave this question open just in case someone has dealt with the same problem and has the solution. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema It's `1.15.0`.

Comment: That's the current BIOS. I don't know then what's wrong with your wifi. Somebody else will need to chime in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I leave it here for anyone dealing with the same problem:

Add in grub the parameter: **pcie_aspm=off**

Comment: What does this line actually do & where to make this change actually